# Create new AWS RDS instance and import data rather than update MySQL version from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I currently have an RDS instance running in AWS based on mysql version 5.6. I need to update it to 5.7 and the main thing recommended is to use the major update functionality in AWS console. However, I have looked through the documentation and it seems quite complicated so I was wondering if the following procedure is a valid workaround that will achieve the same result?

1. Create a new RDS instance based on mysql version 8 (can also do 5.7)
2. Export data in database from original RDS instance into a dump file (using export data functionality of mysql workbench)
3. Reconnect existing bastion EC2 instance to connect to new RDS instance with mysql version 8 (using mysql workbench) and access new RDS through that
4. Import database from dump file created in step 2 into the new RDS instance (using import data functionality of mysql workbench)
5. Configure application to use details of the new RDS instance

Is this a valid procedure? If not, what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure looks good. Do not forget to set inbound rules on the new RDS instance. Using MySQL Workbench is a good way to move data once you connect to your new instance. Once you have the new version all setup, inbound rules set, and data ported to the new instance, be sure to delete the old RDS instance as well.

Comment: is there any way I'd be able to keep it around (for free) just incase anything goes wrong, perhaps by creating a read replica of it, if that's a thing?

Comment: Here is a good answer to that question -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html

Comment: Thank you - I just had one more question. Regarding setting up inbound rules for security, I'm not 100% sure what this entails regarding what I need to set as the availability zones, vpc, subnets and VPC security groups. For the AZ, VPC and subnets is it just making sure the application (EC2 instance) and RDS are all in the same ones? And for vpc security groups how exactly do you make it so that only specific EC2 instances can access it?

Comment: Here is an AWS tutorial that will help - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker. To connect to RDS from your DEV machine, you need to specify the IP address of your dev machine. There is an option that says MyIP when you set a new inbound rule.